# Calling addon functionality from a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've made a firefox addon using the the addon-sdk and I'm trying to write unit tests for it now.

How can I access the addon functionality from the test? From what i see, they are separated, and I cannot simply access the addon functions and variables of my addon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply import the modules of your add-on. For example, if you have a module `lib/foo.js` in your add-on you do:

```
var foo = require("foo");
```

Note that you will only be able to access the methods and variables that the module exports (essentially [properties of its global `exports` object](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/commonjs.html)).

The [`reading-data` example in the Add-on SDK](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/tree/2a3a6e3aa2/examples/reading-data) uses that approach to [load](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/2a3a6e3aa2/examples/reading-data/tests/test-main.js#L1) the [add-on's `main` module](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/2a3a6e3aa2/examples/reading-data/lib/main.js#L10) and to [call the exported method `main()`](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/2a3a6e3aa2/examples/reading-data/tests/test-main.js#L11).

Comment: auch, seems like i need to refactor lots of code. 
For future reference, i'll leave these here: https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/examples/reading-data/lib/main.js#L8 https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/examples/reading-data/tests/test-main.js#L6

Comment: @Quamis: Thank you, I added links to the example source code to my answer. Note that I linked to a specific revision so that the links will continue working even if the examples change.

Comment: even better. not sure this is the right place to ask this, but how can i display an alert or console.info message from the running tests? i'll have to refactor a lots of things and some debugging would be helpful

Comment: @Quamis: Call `console.log()`?

Comment: It's not displaying anything(i've tried `console.info` though, i dont think it would make a difference)

Comment: @Quamis: Don't know it is [supposed to work](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/implementing-simple-addon.html) (see "Logging" section).

Comment: Thanks man, tested now and it seems like `console.log` works as expected.. `console.info` isn't working though